# NSMutableArray addObject: giving Error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

Here is the code what I am trying..

but the thing is when I load the view first time it works.. doesn't give any problem..

but when i try to load view again and call this code.. it gives error on `arrMain addObject:`

I am trying to look over it but don't find anything..

can anyone please help??

```
NSUserDefaults *ds = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *arrMain = [ds objectForKey:@"files"];
int i;

if([arrMain count] > 0)
{
    i = [arrMain count] + 1;

}
else
{
    arrMain = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    i = 1;
}
NSLog(@"File Name To Be Saved %d.txt",i);

NSArray *sd = [[NSArray alloc] init];
sd = [dict componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict1 setObject:[sd objectAtIndex:[sd count] - 1] forKey:@"name"];
NSString *OrgFilename = [sd objectAtIndex:[sd count] - 1];
NSArray *extArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
extArr = [OrgFilename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *flExt = [extArr    objectAtIndex:1];
[dict1 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.txt",i,flExt] forKey:@"filename"];

// *** error happens VVVV
[arrMain addObject:dict1];
// *** error happens ^^^^

[ds setObject:arrMain forKey:@"files"];
[ds synchronize];
```

Comment: 1) what error are you getting? 2) are you using ARC?

Comment: Hello.. no i am not using arc.. the problem is it dont print any error. just say program received signal SIGBART

Comment: Cut down the code so you have the minimum that shows the issue - you have odd bits of unrelated code,

Comment: ok done.. can you please see what is the issue.. actually this wont come if i run first time.. but as soon as i run it for second time i get this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to retrieve a `NSMutableArray` from the `NSUserDefaults`. It will not be returning a `NSMutableArray`, but a `NSArray` instead. You will want to do:

```
NSMutableArray *arrMain = [[[ds objectForKey:@"files"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

The reason it "worked" the first time through was `arrMain` was nil, so you created a valid `NSMutableArray`, then saved it into the `NSUserDefaults`. After that, you got a valid object (non-nil), but it wasn't the type you were expecting. Since `-[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]` returns a `id` type, it happily assigned it your `NSMutableArray` object, even though it wasn't that type.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but that would cause an `invalid selector sent to instance of NSArray` to be logged to the console, while OP states that there is no error printed, just a SIGABRT

Comment: No, because the type of the object is `NSMutableArray`, so it will happily agree to attempt the call of that method.

Comment: nope, the object is just casted to NSMutableArray*. In the case of Objects, this is just for the compiler. The actual object in memory will still be an NSArray and thus will not respond to `addObject` and throw an exception.

Comment: Exactly, it is casted as a `NSMutableArray`. I was not being clear when I said the "type of object is `NSMutableArray`". I meant the declared type. The underlying type is a `NSArray` of course. And, it will cause a SIGABRT.

Comment: Hello @gschandler it worked.. thanks.. though i now understand that its underlying type is NSArray so it may cause an SIGABRT.. but its working rite now... thanks guys.. this helps me to understand what should i use.. thanks..